# Problem dealing with $\sum \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$ and its convergence

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\text{If} \ S=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin (n)}{n}, \ \text{then what is} \ 2S+1$$

I know that $\sum \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$ converges. But now what do I do?

Comment: That depends a bit on just how you know that the series converges.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What do you mean. not quite understanding

Comment: You write that you know that the series converges. How do you know that the series converges?

Comment: Hint: what is the value of the sum from $-1$ to $-\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to prove this here, but we know that (ask another question if you don't):
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k }{k} = -\log(1-x)$$
For any $x$ s.t. $|x|\leq 1, x\neq 1$:
$$S= \text{Im} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i n}}{n} = -\text{Im}(\log(1-e^{i} ))$$
Now with some trig:
$$1-e^i = 1-\cos 1 -i \sin 1 = 2\sin \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin \frac{1}{2} - i \cos \frac{1}{2} \right) = 2\exp\left(\frac{(1-\pi)i}{2}\right) \sin \frac{1}{2}$$
Therefore,
$$S= \text{Im}(\log(1-e^{i} )) = \text{Im}\left(\frac{(\pi-1)i}{2} - \log \left(2\sin \frac{1}{2}\right) \right) = \frac{\pi-1}{2} $$ 
$$\therefore  2S+1 =\pi$$